# WiX - Sequencing Custom Action and Service Install

Tags: .net, wix

I'm putting together an install for a Windows Service (managed). I'd like to be able to update its config file based on user input from a dialog. The config file gets updated properly and the windows service gets installed, but it doesn't look like the service is picking up the changes in the config. Am I messing up with the sequencing?  I want to run my Custom Action "ServiceConfig" before the service gets installed and started.

Here is a scrubbed excerpt from my WiX files:

```
<Component Id="cmpXyzService.exe" Guid="NOTAREAL-GUID-90X5-12C5-ABC123XYZ890">
    <File Id="file_XyzService.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\XyzService.exe" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="InstallXyzService" Name="Service.XYZ" DisplayName="XYZ Service" Start="auto" Vital="yes" Interactive="no" ErrorControl="normal" Type="ownProcess" />
    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControlXyzService" Name="Service.XYZ" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no"/>
</Component>

<CustomAction Id="SetPropertiesForService" Property="ServiceConfig" Value="[SERVICEINSTANCENAME],[CONFIGVALUE1],[CONFIGVALUE2]" />
<Binary Id="UpdateConfigFileCustomAction.CA.dll" SourceFile="$(var.UpdateConfigFileCustomActionDir)\UpdateConfigFileCustomAction.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="ServiceConfig" BinaryKey="UpdateConfigFileCustomAction.CA.dll" DllEntry="EditConfigFile" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetPropertiesForService" Before="ServiceConfig" >NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="ServiceConfig" After="InstallFiles" >NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here's a trimmed-down copy of the InstallExecuteSequence table from Orca

```
StopServices    VersionNT       1900
DeleteServices  VersionNT       2000
RemoveFiles                     3500
InstallFiles                    4000
SetPropertiesForService NOT Installed   4001
ServiceConfig     NOT Installed 4002
InstallServices VersionNT       5800
StartServices   VersionNT       5900
RegisterUser                    6000
RegisterProduct                 6100
MsiPublishAssemblies            6250
PublishFeatures                 6300
PublishProduct                  6400
InstallFinalize                 6600
RemoveExistingProducts          6601
```

Apologies if I have edited out something important - I didn't want to dump everything I had. I believe I've included everything relevant.

Comment: Have you had a look at the MSI log (you need to enable MSI logging via the registry or the /l switch on the msiexec command line.) That will give you more of an idea about what order things are happening in.

Comment: Hi Stephen, yes the log file shows my CA executing just before the InstallServices op's. I wonder whether the ServiceInstall actions behave exactly like the InstallUtil.exe? We have logic in the Installer constructor that doesn't look like it's being executed.

Comment: [Yikes](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07131.html) - does anyone know if this is still the current state of affairs? There is a reference to something Bob (Arnason?) implemented in WiX 3 - is this ServiceInstall in general, or something that handles Installer types?

Comment: [This caused a kerfuffle back in 2006](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00724.html). I did find [this workaround](http://netinverse.com/devblogs/wix/how-to-invoke-installutilexe-in-wix-custom-action-to-call-your-managed-installer-class/278/) though. Basically, WiX doesn't recognize the RunInstallerAttribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per last comment:

[This caused a kerfuffle back in 2006](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00724.html). I did find [this workaround](http://netinverse.com/devblogs/wix/how-to-invoke-installutilexe-in-wix-custom-action-to-call-your-managed-installer-class/278/) though. Basically, WiX doesn't recognize the RunInstallerAttribute.

Comment: The workaround link leads to 404. Can you please share the details ?

Comment: Wow, this was a long time ago. *Maybe* this? http://blog.kaide.net/post/2011/09/12/How-To-Execute-InstallUtil-With-WIX-35.aspx

Comment: Is this it? Seriously. Plus, the fact that this is still an issue today.....
https://web.archive.org/web/20140521090813/http://blog.kaide.net/post/2011/09/12/How-To-Execute-InstallUtil-With-WIX-35.aspx